# How can I access the implicit object?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

At [OAuth 2.0 Resource Server Multi-tenancy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/multitenancy.html) the following example is given:

> ```
> @Bean
> AuthenticationManagerResolver<HttpServletRequest> tokenAuthenticationManagerResolver
>        (JwtDecoder jwtDecoder, OpaqueTokenIntrospector opaqueTokenIntrospector) {
>    AuthenticationManager jwt = new ProviderManager(new JwtAuthenticationProvider(jwtDecoder));
>    AuthenticationManager opaqueToken = new ProviderManager(
>             new OpaqueTokenAuthenticationProvider(opaqueTokenIntrospector));
>    return (request) -> useJwt(request) ? jwt : opaqueToken;
> }
> ```

Sorry but my issue reading this is, where is `request`? It is not passed to the method at all and stuff like this confuses the hell out of me when reading documentation. Can anyone enlighten me what I should look for?

I need to access the `request` object to further implement the logic.

Comment: `AuthenticationManagerResolver` is a "functional interface" (an interface defining only one method) ... Since we/the sample want/s to return an `AuthenticationManagerResolver<HttpServletRequest>`, we need to implement `resolve(HttpServletRequest request)` method...

Comment: And whoever will use that "resolver" (method) must/will provide a `HttpServletRequest` (hopefully not null;)

Comment: (the implementation of `resolve(request)` method you provide with (lambda) `(request) -> useJwt(request) ? jwt : opaqueToken;`)